# display only specific div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

The jQuery code below works such that on clicking a link (class address), it slides down a box, and prints all text from the details.php file in the #msg div. However, I want to display only one div (#address), present in the details.php.  How can this be done? thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.address').click(function() {
            $('#box).slideDown("slow");               
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
              url: "details.php",
              success: function(html){
                $("#msg").html(html);
                } 
            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a jQuery object out of the returned data and apply a selector to it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.address').click(function() {
            $('#box').slideDown("slow");               
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
              url: "details.php",
              success: function(html){
                $("#msg").html($(html).find('#address').html());
                } 
            });

        });
    });
```

Also, note that this would probably be a good candidate to use `.one('click', function() {})` since you probably don't want to load the address every time it is clicked, but rather just the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also about .one suggestion. However I'm having a problem, that the code doesnt seem to work. details.php file is very simple, contains only few divs, and text inside the divs. The code which i posted works fine, however when to use your code (the modified line inside success), it does not work. Any clue?

Comment: @user547969, step into the function in firebug or chrome dev tools and see what $(html).find('#address') is returning.  Perhaps the returned HTML isn't exactly what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a close quote on your 3rd line if that helps.

```
$('#box').slideDown("slow");
```